# How would i make an each loop in svelte reactive

Tags: javascript, svelte

i have this svelte code:

```html
    <!--connectprom is a Promise that resolves when connect is ran--->
    {#await connectprom}
    <!--User hasnt yet connected to the server-->
    <form on:submit|preventDefault={connect}>
        <label for="un">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="un">
    </form>
    {:then}
    <!--After the form was submited (user is connected)-->    
    Welcome, <p class="name text-blue-300">{username}</p>
    <!--When send is ran it sends the data from the form to the socket.io server-->
    <form class="shadow-lg rounded-lg" on:submit|preventDefault={send} align="center">
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <input type="text" id="msg">
    </form>
    {#each messages as msg}
    <Message username=msg.username content=msg.content/>
    {/each}
    {/await}
```

Is It Possible for the #each statement to run reactively? If not is there a workaround to do so?

Comment: Hi. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally the `{#each}` statement is run reactively, and should update if the variable `messages` changes.

BUT, for Svelte to register an update in an array, you have to reassign the variable.

General example Code from the Svelte Docs:

```js
numbers = [] //TODO: We want a function that adds an item to the end of the array, that is the array Length + 1, so after a few runs it should look like this: [1,2,3,4, ...]

//This doesn't work
function addNumber() {
    numbers.push(numbers.length + 1); //The variable is not reassigned
}

//This does work!
function addNumber() {
    numbers.push(numbers.length + 1);
    numbers = numbers; //This is the reassignment
}

// OR
function addNumber() {
    numbers = [...numbers, numbers.length + 1]; //And this is also the reassignment
}
```

And some Example Code for your problem:

```js
messages = [] //TODO: Have a function that appends a message to the array and forces the {#each} "loop" to update

//This doesn't work
function addMessage(newMessage) {
    messages.push(newMessage); // It's just adding to the array but the array isn't "registered" as updated
}

//This does work!
function addMessage(newMessage) {
    messages.push(newMessage);
    messages = messages; //This is the reassignment and causes the update
}

// OR
function addMessage(newMessage) {
    messages = [...messages, newMessage]; //Another way to add to it and reassign it to also cause an update
}
```

So I think that you have to change the way you append messages to the `messages` array.

Reference and Examples: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

Comment: **Thanks so much!, My code works now.**

Comment: Can you mark your question as answered, so that it gets closed ?

Comment: yes sorry im kinda new to stackoverflow